# Permitir envio automatico de email com Outlook

Tags: vba

Ola, preciso enviar vários emails para diferentes endereços de forma automática, porém quando o `VBA` inicia o processo de envio abre uma caixa de alerta solicitando minha permissão para concluir a tarefa.

Alguém sabe como anular esse alerta e enviar o email?

O codigo de envio de email:

```
Function Enviar_dados_celulas_email(subject As String, destiny As String, body As Range, introductin As String)

' selecão da planilha desejada.
If destiny <> "" Then
    body.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
End If

   With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Introduction = introductin
      .Item.To = destiny
      .Item.subject = subject
      .Item.Send
   End With
[D1].Select


End Function
```

tenho este outro jeito, porém nao consigo enviar umar range no corppo do email D:

```
Function Enviar_dados_celulas_email(subject As String, destiny As String, body As Range, introduction As String)

Dim oOutlookApp As Object, oOutlookMessage As Object
Set oOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oOutlookMessage = oOutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

With oOutlookMessage
    .subject = subject
    .To = destiny
    .body = body
    .Display
     SendKeys "%e"
End With

Set objMsg = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Ola. Coloque o código que esta a usar para enviar os *emails* na pergunta para o podermos ajudar.

Comment: Alguém???????????????

Comment: Esse código não ajudou muito. Você só colocou a função do Enviar Emails, precisamos saber como você está usando a função na sub, um exemplo funcional.

Comment: sub qualquer
enviar_email = Enviar_dados_celulas_email("qualquer assunto",endereco@email.com, Range("A1:I17"), "segue exemplo")
end sub

Comment: essa ta dificil D:

Comment: alguem por please

Answer (score 1):

Aqui funcionou normal sem nenhuma janela de notificação, com o código que você forneceu:

```
Function Enviar_dados_celulas_email(subject As String, destiny As String, body As Range, introductin As String)

' selecão da planilha desejada.
If destiny <> "" Then
    body.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
End If

   With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Introduction = introductin
      .Item.To = destiny
      .Item.subject = subject
      .Item.Send
   End With
[D1].Select

End Function
```

sub qualquer:

```
Sub qualquer()

enviar_email = Enviar_dados_celulas_email("qualquer assunto", "SEUEMAIL@EMAIL.COM", Range("A1:A2"), "segue exemplo")

End Sub
```

Talvez porque eu já estava com o outlook aberto, mandou automático; Em todo caso tente utilizar o  `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` e `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` antes de executar a função (na sub) e no final não esqueça de trocar pra `True`.

Comment: Man, eu acho que pq o meu email é da empresa e tem firewall que estou tendo esse problema... ja havia tentado display alerts
eu consegui enviar sem alerta de permissão com um outro método de envio, porém nessa nova maneira, não estou conseguindo colocar uma range  no corpo do email. D:

Comment: Edite a pergunta com esse segundo jeito, pra ver se conseguimos ajudar você no problema.

Comment: Ja editei, mantive os 2 codigos, obrigado.

Comment: Aguem me ajuda por favor D=